# Controlling the origin of rotation in a CSS transform on the right hand side of a div

Tags: css

If I apply this rule to a div (with variable content)

```
position: absolute;
left: 0; 
top: 0;
transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
transform-origin: 0 0 0;
```

It rotates from its top left corner and 'hangs' in the top left corner of its parent. It doesn't move no matter what size the div

How can I do the same in the right hand corner, ie rotate it so it 'hangs' in the right hand corner of its parent and rotates from its top left.

the starting point is

```
position: absolute;
right: 0; 
top: 0;
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform-origin: 100% 0 ;
```

but it 'sticks up' rather than 'hangs down'.

I can, of course, move it with `right` and `top` but those values are different for different size of content.

Comment: can you provide the working code please of what you have tried.. this will help for better understanding

Comment: https://codepen.io/chrispink/pen/qmZvKp You'll see an extra piece of text positioned where I want it to be but the `top` value is dependent on the size of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, as all are when you know, very simple. Thanks to Sahil for making me mock it up in Codepen, easier to see the issue than when on a live page full of data.

```
position: absolute;
right: 0; 
top: 0;
transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100%);
transform-origin: 100% 0 ;
```

ie the addition of `translateX(100%);` to the transform

Comment: Well, hopefully it will help someone else some day.